# VBA code to call different sheet command button

Tags: excel, vba

VBA code to call command button from another sheet(in same workbook)?

Suppose I have two command button and one in Sheet1 and second in Sheet2. Then how to call second sheet2 command button from sheet1.

Comment: Call `name of your sub`

Comment: `Sheet2.YourMethodNameHere`

Comment: So what happened with this thread?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the **private** part of the Macro name, then you can call it.

[image]

Comment: Please note that [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). While we are praying this to questioners this must be valid for both: questions *and* answers. • Why? Because your images don't show anything that cannot be shown with code formatted as code block. And because it prevents everyone from easily copying the code. So only disadvantages by using images of code and no advantage makes it a bad practice in my eyes!

Comment: @Pᴇʜ in this case an image is OK., it shows exactly what need to be done to make the solution work.