# Combining ActiveX Buttons from Multiple Sheets to One Button

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I am trying to create a button in an excel spreadsheet that activates every other button in the workbook in a particular order. These buttons are located in 4 different sheets. I attempted to simply create a button in one sheet, and call the other buttons from this button as below:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Button2_Click
    Button3_Click
    Button4_Click
    Button5_Click
    Button6_Click
End Sub
```

This did not work. I was thinking that maybe I need some sort of way to reference the sheet that each button is in?

Comment: Check out this thread...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598143/vba-code-to-call-different-sheet-command-button/53598843#53598843

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers are `Private` for a reason. Making them `Public` will work, but isn't what you should be doing.

Move the code out of these handlers and into their own public procedures; then invoke these procedures from the respective handlers - and invoke the same procedures in the appropriate order from this commandbutton handler.

For example you take this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click()
    'do stuff
End Sub
```

Turn it into this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click()
    DoStuff
End Sub

Public Sub DoStuff()
    'do stuff
End Sub
```

Then you can invoke `DoStuff` from wherever you need to.

Event handlers should never be invoked directly, and never need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Even Private event handlers within sheet modules can be started by following way.
Assuming you have a worksheet named "ActiveXButtons" (its caption) with Button2 on it and following button event code within that worksheet:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click()
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Then you can trigger above button's event by addressing the worksheet's codename indirectly:

```
Application.Run Worksheets("ActiveXButtons").CodeName & ".Button2_Click"
```

or shortened:

```
Run “Sheet2.Button2_Click“
```